# codeigniter jquery sortable save to database

Tags: jquery-ui, codeigniter

I am trying to save the order of a list of images to the database when using jquery sortable. 
I feel i am very close, but cant get my head around the final details.
I am working with CI 2.1.3 and jquery-ui 1.10.3.

I have a dynamicaly generated list with an image:

```
<ul id="order">
<li id="item-1"><img src="abc.jpg" /></li>
<li id="item-2"><img src="def.jpg" /></li>
<li id="item-3"><img src="ghi.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

And the following Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

        $( "#order" ).sortable({
            opacity: 0.6,
            cursor: 'move',

            update: function(event, ui){
 var order = $(this).sortable("serialize");
 console.log(order);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/gridrobin/home/save_order",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: order,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#test").html(data);
                    }

                });
                }

            });

});
</script>
```

This works fine and i can reorder my list. Now i want to save the new order to the database. I send the ajax post to the controller and it comes through. I checked with a var_dump.

```
//var_dump($_POST);

        $items = $this->input->post('item');
        $total_items = count($this->input->post('item'));

        echo '<h3>Debugging</h3>';
        echo "<p>Total items sent: $total_items</p>";

        $this->rd_model->update_order($total_items, $items);
```

Then I send this data to my model:

```
 for($item = 0; $item < $total_items; $item++ )
        {

            $data = array(
                    'id' => $items[$item],
                    'order' => $order = $item
            );

            $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);

            $this->db->update('portfolio_items', $data);
            echo '<br />'.$this->db->last_query();
        }
```

And echo out the last db-query for debugging.

Now when i switch item 1 and item 2, i get a 500 internal error. When i switch them back, i receive the echo of the last query executed, which seems fine.

```
UPDATE `portfolio_items` SET `order` = 1 WHERE `id` = '1'
UPDATE `portfolio_items` SET `order` = 2 WHERE `id` = '2'
UPDATE `portfolio_items` SET `order` = 3 WHERE `id` = '3'
```

I dont quite understand why the database updates when th list is switched back to its orignial state, but not otherwise.

**UPDATE**
For people with the same problem, sakibmoon answer helped me a lot, but the main problem was a duplicate entry error, because apparently i had set the order table as a unique index...

Comment: I copied what you have in the jQuery script, but when I run the var_dump in the controller I get an empty array. Is there anything else you had to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within your data array in the model. Change that with this -

```
$data = array(
                'id' => $items[$item],
                'order' => $item+1
        );
```

Also change the update line -

```
    $this->db->update('portfolio_items', $data['order']);
```

**UPDATE**:

Couple of changes. Change the update to this-

```
$this->db->update('portfolio_items', array('order' => $data['order']));
```

The code is working now if I set `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE` in `config.php`. But you should set it to `TRUE`. I don't know how to make that work. All I know is that you have to send csrf_token with your ajax call. You should create a separate question for that. This question title means something entirely different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It still does not work though... I get an error 500 everytime now (with csrf = FALSE). I have tried to enable csrf and include the token in the data, but it still give me this error.  When csrf = FALSE, i can print_r the $data array. But when I include the database query, I get the error.

Comment: Are you making call on different domain?

Comment: No, i am on my localhost. The call goes from http://localhost/gridrobin/ to http://localhost/gridrobin/index.php/home/save_order

Comment: Thank you for your update. I dont get errors if i put the db query outside the for statement, when i put them inside i do get the error. And if i put them outside the for statement, it seems like it works but the database isnt affected... Thank you for your time btw!