# Query-string changes on $.ajax

Tags: jquery, post, jquery-ui-sortable

My issue is that my content of the data is changes when sent with post to my controller in CodeIgniter.

I send:

```
item[]=113&item[]=114&item[]=164&item[]=125&item[]=163&item[]=131&item[]=130
```

and recieve:

```
item[]=113&item;[]=114&item;[]=164&item;[]=125&item;[]=163&item;[]=131&item;[]=130
```

My view:

```
$(".todo-list").sortable({
update: function(event, ui) {

  var path = "<?php echo base_url();?>news/sort_posts/";
  var news_var =  'item[]=113&item[]=114&item[]=164&item[]=125&item[]=163&item[]=131&item[]=130'; 
  // var news_var =  $('.sortme').sortable('serialize');
  console.log(news_var);

   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: path, 
     data: { news: news_var, <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?> : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>' }, 
     dataType: "text",  
     cache:false,
     success: function(data){ alert('success'); },
    error: function(data){ alert("fail"); }
    })
},
  distance: 15 
});
```

My controller:

```
public function sort_posts()
{

   $news = $this->input->post('news');
   parse_str($news, $pageOrder);

   if(!empty($news)) { 
      $this->db->insert('tester', array('test1' => '$news isset', 'test2' => $news));
   } else { 
      $this->db->insert('tester', array('test1' => '$news empty')); 
   } 


   foreach ($pageOrder['item'] as $key => $value) {

   $data = array('sort' => $key);
   $this->db->where('id', $value);
   $this->db->update('m_news_posts', $data);

   }
}

// $news = item[]=113&item;[]=114&item;[]=164&item;[]=125&item;[]=163&item;[]=131&item;[]=130;
```

Comment: you need to pass the actual item array into the data object, let jQuery serialize it. It's serializing a serialized string which is causing problems. Otherwise you would need to do all of the serializing for the other data as well and only pass a serialized string to `data`

Comment: Hmm.. 
I think I understandd.. Do you want me to move php's parse_str($news, $pageOrder); to be done with jQuery in the view-file?

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Tried in numberous of ways :)

Comment: This helped me to solve this issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764555/codeigniter-jquery-sortable-save-to-database